# How to add a rectangle to a listbox in Winforms

Tags: winforms, user-interface

I want to add UI elemnts to a ListBox in Winforms.
When I add an Elipse or a Rectangle - What i get in the list is Object.ToString().
How can i get the behavior of WPF that when i insert UI Elements to the ListBox.Items - I will see the object i have inserted and not the string represention of it?

Comment: `How can I get the behavior of WPF?` - Use WPF. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, you don't really need it.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point is to declare an interface that's suitable to do what's necessary to draw shapes.  Your concrete Shape classes should implement that interface:

```
    public interface IShape {
        Rectangle Measure();
        void Draw(Graphics g);
        // etc...
    }
```

You should set the ListBox's DrawMode property to DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable.  Which requires you to implement its MeasureItem event handler, needed to determine how large the listbox item should be to display the shape:

```
    void listBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e) {
        e.ItemWidth = listBox1.ClientSize.Width;
        var shape = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as IShape;
        if (shape != null) e.ItemHeight = shape.Measure().Height;
    }
```

And you need to implement an event handler for the DrawItem event to draw the shape:

```
    void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
        e.DrawBackground();
        var shape = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as IShape;
        if (shape != null) shape.Draw(e.Graphics);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```